# Shared Stored procedures for Multiple Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have an application that has multiple identical databases apart from customer customizations. we would like to centralize the stored procedures that are common across all databases. Currently, we are having problems with keeping all databases up to date as customizations are done in the common database.

We have tried to make some customer-specific stored procedures which are called from our "Global" stored procedures. This works as long as all the people that have access to the database adhere to the rules. But as with all rules the bosses do not follow them. :(

So i would like to make a stored procedure truly Global that is executed from a central location and not the individual database.

I have already tried storing stored procedures in a central database and then have a job copy them to all databases. this resulted in some seriously pissed-off bosses. :(

Anybody have some good ideas for this?

Comment: The job to copy stored procedures around seems like the way to go, what went wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [3rd party database comparison and synchronization tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_Compare_Tools) to copy stored procedures from "Global" database to "local" databases

Comment: Nothing went wrong.. The one boss just likes being able to change procedures and test in production.. I know i should just find another job. but i do not have the balls. :(